# How do I get a Dlink DWA-130 working?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, usb, ndiswrapper, adapter

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 in my system and I'm having issue with my wireless usb adapter.  I installed ndiswrapper in my system and load my .inf file for my usb wifi adapter and everything seems to be working fine but whenever I restart my system, my wifi stopped working and the wireless option in the network from system settings is missing.

My quick fix to this is to remove the driver from ndiswrapper and install the .inf again.  Is there a way that Ubuntu 11.10 automatically recognize the driver for my usb wifi adapter whenever I boot my system without removing and installing it from ndiswrapper?  I never had this issue with Ubuntu 11.04.  Please help!

Comment: Nice job finding a solution, it would be great if you could add hardware information to this question so the next person who comes along can find this!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Ahh yes that's a good idea.  The USB wireless adapter that I'm using is D-link DWA-130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load new driver module (may not be necessary any longer, but does no harm either):

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Add the module to `/etc/modules` to have it load automatically:

```
echo 'ndiswrapper' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Create alias directive:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

References:

- [Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=662585)
- http://www.pronetworks.org/forums/ndiswrapper-load-at-startup-solved-t103019.html